# What browser-internal operations prevent requestAnimationFrame from being invoked?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom, cross-browser

I understand the answer to this question is very browser (and even browser version) specific, but I was hoping there might be some general rules or behaviors that apply everywhere.

I know the execution time of my JavaScript in the requestAnimationFrame callback will slow down the rate of invocation.  But what about the rest of the browser activity that my code influences but doesn't necessarily control? Does all of the reflow and layout and painting activity caused by my DOM changes happen synchronously before the subsequent invocation of the requestAnimationFrame callback?  Or is there a chance that the next callback will be invoked before the pixels from previous changes settle on the screen?

Comment: the first that instantly comes to mind is garbage collector, also disk/network access might cause this as well as cpu/gpu spikes

Answer (score 1):

Normally everything the browser need to do, repaint, handle setTimeout and setInterval is places as an event in an event queue and executed one by one.

`requestAnimationFrame` is a special case as this synchronizes to the VBLANK gap on your monitor which means the callback WILL be called when a VBLANK occur.

As freakish says in his answer, Javascript is single-threaded, hence the event queue, but in this case the browser will force an event forward (go ahead of the current queue).

What happens exact at callback is that everything currently drawn to canvas is "blitted" to browser's bitmap (what you see on screen), then continues with the function. Whatever is the result from other events are also updated at this point (even if they are in the progress - internally an element is processed to its own bitmap, then drawn to the screen as the canvas element IIRC).

Even if the callback happen when it's supposed to doesn't mean for example a paint event cannot occur in between calls in the callback function itself. This will of course influence performance.

The next thing then is that from frame 0 to frame 1 you have a time budget, usually around 16.7 ms (@ 60Hz). If your task is not completed within this budget nothing happens, but when you call `requestAnimationFrame` it will not callback until next VBLANK happens ("skipping a heart-beat") and you will notice this as jerks in the animation (as you will see with setTimeout/setInternval as they don't sync to VBLANK and will from time to time fall between updates resulting in jerks - this is the main reason why `requestAnimationFrame` is offered together with its more low-level construction which makes it more performant in itself).

`requestAnimationFrame` callback rate is reduced to half (seems to be consistent across browsers) when the tab is inactive (or if there is hardware-limits or running on batteries). The difference is that now the event is not forced every ~16.7 ms, but at ~33.4 ms and the other events are executed as before (repaint etc.) (not sure if vendors have adopted the slow-down for event queues in general though).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript (in browsers) is single-threaded so everything happens sequentially. From that point of view everything affects everything. But as long as these operations take less time then a frame (and hopefuly they will) you should not worry about it.

One of the benefits is that you don't have to worry about synchronization. Next call won't happen before previous callback finishes all it has to do.